# 1 is automatically added before > or >> when running a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to compile a very simple command in a `.bat` file.

```
whoami > "Desktop/laptop.txt"
```

However, when I run it, `cmd.exe` interprets it as:

```
whoami 1> "Desktop/laptop.txt"
```

This is invalid due to the number `1` added before the `>`. The command does not run.

I can't find a way to get this number `1` to go away.

Comment: `whoami 1>file.dat` works for me.  `1>` is equivalent to `>` on its own, and redirects stdout.  `2>` can be used to redirect stderr.

Comment: It is not invalid, but actually the correct usage. Using `>`, is simply a lazy way of using `1>` because StdOut, is the default for the redirection operator. You are actually only seeing the command which is being run. If it is not necessary to see the actual command being run, _(it rarely is)_, you could use `@WhoAmI > "Desktop\laptop.txt"` _(where prepending with `@` directly turns of its echoing)_. If you don't need to see any of this echoing you could, begin your batch file with an `@Echo Off` instruction to turn off all of this echoing, instead of prepending each individual command.

Answer (score 1):

To conclude what said in comments, the command line interpreter, interprets `>` (redirection character) and `>>` (append character) as `1>` and `1>>` respectively if they are alone, e.g. `echo sth > filename` or `echo sth >> filename`.

That is because the numeric handles are as follows:

- `0` redirects/appends **STDIN** to somewhere specified.
- `1` redirects/appends **STDOUT** to somewhere specified.
- `2` redirects/appends **STDERR** to somewhere specified
- `3-9` are undefined

So, when you type your command:

```bat
whoami > "Desktop/laptop.txt"
```

interpreter cannot understand it **and automatically** makes it `1> ...` because it assumes you want to redirect STDOUT to `Desktop/laptop.txt`.

See some interesting links for further reading:

- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133 and especially phase 2

Comment: *"interpreter cannot understand it **and automatically** makes it `1> ...`* - eh, I don't think I would say that. The interpreter understands just fine. I think it is more about showing the user how the parser is interpreting the the command by explicitly writing the handle as 1 (meaning stdout).

Comment: When you start doing PowerShell, there are several more output streams. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/